# Exporting to excel using Apache poi within IDE works but when i create runnable jar it doesn't

Tags: java, excel, javafx, apache-poi

I'm using Netbeans 8.2 and i create jar by clicking on `clean and build` icon, runnable jar works except when i want data to export to excel.

This is logic for exporting to excel:

```
public static void exportToExcel(TableView<T> tableView, Stage stage) {

    HSSFWorkbook hssfWorkbook = new HSSFWorkbook();
    HSSFSheet hssfSheet = hssfWorkbook.createSheet("Sheet1");
    HSSFRow firstRow = hssfSheet.createRow(0);

    //Getting column width
    ExcelPropertiesCustomization.getColumnWidth(hssfSheet);
 
    // Getting title properties
    CellStyle naslov = ExcelPropertiesCustomization.getTitleProperties(hssfWorkbook);
    //set titles of columns
    for (int i = 0; i < tableView.getColumns().size(); i++) {
        firstRow.createCell(i).setCellValue(tableView.getColumns().get(i).getText());
        firstRow.getCell(i).setCellStyle(naslov);
    }
    // set cells for rest of the table
    for (int i = 0; i < tableView.getItems().size(); i++) {
        HSSFRow hssfRow = hssfSheet.createRow(i + 1);
        for (int col = 0; col < tableView.getColumns().size(); col++) {
            Object celValue = tableView.getColumns().get(col).getCellObservableValue(i).getValue();
            try {
                if (celValue != null) {
                    hssfRow.createCell(col).setCellValue(Double.parseDouble(celValue.toString()));
                }
            } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
                hssfRow.createCell(col).setCellValue(celValue.toString());
            } catch (NullPointerException e) {
                System.out.println(e);
            }
        }
    }

    //save excel file and close the workbook
    try {
        File file = new File("FXdatabase.xls");
        FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(file);
        hssfWorkbook.write(out);
        FileChooser fileChooser = new FileChooser();
        FileChooser.ExtensionFilter extFilter = new FileChooser.ExtensionFilter("XLS files (*.xls)", "*.xls");
        fileChooser.getExtensionFilters().add(extFilter);
        File dest = fileChooser.showSaveDialog(stage);
        if (dest != null) {
            try {
                Files.copy(file.toPath(), dest.toPath());
            } catch (IOException ex) {
                System.err.println(ex);
            }
        }
        out.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        System.out.prinln(e);
    }
}
```

It's not my first time that i export to excel using apache poi, but i never encouter this problem(i also have new lap top, don't know if that has something to do with problem), i suspect it's `IOException`. What can i do?

Comment: @AxelRichter Sorry about that in my code actually is `hssfWorkbook.write(out);`. I was just messing with code and forgot to fix it back.

Comment: @AxelRichter I fix it, still jar doesn't working. Something else to try?

Comment: @AxelRichter so i wrote alert inside `IOException catch` block and that alert pops up when i click on excel button.

Comment: @AxelRichter But e.printStackTrace will never be hit, since like i said in IDE everything works fine. And i can't put alert on `e.printStackTrace();` since it dosen't return anything. So i put alert like this `alert.setHeaderText(e.getMessage());` After that i get `FXdatabase.xls (Access is denied)`.